# Data for plotting tephigrams

Tags: meteorology, geography, measurements, open-data

I want to plot some [tephigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tephigram).
Where can I find pressure, temperature and dewpoint data in text format?

Comment: Did you search this site first? You can also check [Opendata.SE].

Answer (score 3):

Since OP wants data in text format to plot pressure, temperature and dew point data this site [University of Wyoming soundings map](http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html) does provide data in a text format as shown in this example for [Essen Germany](http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=europe&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=03&FROM=2000&TO=2000&STNM=10410).

Answer (score 1):

Archive, reanalysis and forecast data of those variables worldwide from GFS model can be accessed at [NOAA Ready](https://www.ready.noaa.gov/READYcmet.php).

This is an example of those variables in the forecast for a given location:

[image]

And if you click the "Text Result" ling before the meteorogram you can access a tab-delimited text file that looks like this:

[image]